# Is it possible to create a local Google Colab server?

Tags: google-colaboratory

For individuals with limited Internet availability, is there any way to stand-up a local Google-Colab server for a local network?

In our case, we need to use Jupyter from Google-Colab at a site with limited Internet access.  The Internet is only available for a few hours a day and the connection is weak at best.  We would like to stand-up a local server with Google-Colab so that work can continue when the Internet is unavailable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colab supports [local Jupyter backends](http://research.google.com/colaboratory/local-runtimes.html). But, you'll need an Internet connection to load the Colab website.